# React inline style with ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, inline, ternary

Having a Checkbox element like this:

```
<Checkbox
    checked={this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1}
/>
```

When that index has a positive value the checkbox gets checked.

I want to add different colors to the checkbox, for example if it is unchecked - blue, checked - red.

So I tried to do it like this:

```
<Checkbox
   checked={this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1}
   {(this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1) ? style={{ color: 'red' }} : style={{ color: 'blue' }}}
   />
```

but it doesn't work.

Another try:

```
<Checkbox
   checked={this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1}
   style={(this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1) ? {{ color: 'red' }} : {{ color: 'blue' }} }
   />
```

Is it possible to set the style inline with ternary operators and I'm doing it wrong or should I try a different way?

Comment: <Checkbox style={condition ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'blue' } }/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second try only doesn't work because you have too many `{}` in it. Remember that the outer `{}` around the property value are to delimit a JSX expression; the contents of the expression are just JavaScript, so an object just uses a single pair of `{}`.

But I wouldn't create separate objects (though that's fine), I'd just switch out the value:

```
      v−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v−− JSX expression delimiters
style={{color: this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1 ? 'red' : 'blue' }}
       ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−− Object literal delimiters
```

But just for completeness, your second attempt corrected looks like this:

```
      v−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v−− JSX expression delimiters
style={this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1 ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'blue' } }
                                                     ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−− Object literal delimiters
```

...and that way is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do maybe is to separate into a function which generates the value. Even if ternary operator is good for this case, probably make the code not that readable in this way.

I would try as:

```
<Checkbox checked={this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1}
          style={getStyle()} />
```

And create a function for this purpose:

```
const getStyle = () => {
   return {
      color: this.props.someValues.indexOf(myValue) > -1 ? 'red' : 'blue'
   }
}
```

So still you can keep your ternary operator but in a much readable way.

I hope this helps!